# Best way to do the same than you can do with nested linearlayouts

Tags: android, performance, layout, nested, android-linearlayout

I have to create a windows8 like screen. I create it easily using nested linearlayouts. I know from a performance point of view it is not a good idea be having nested linearlayouts, so I want to ask you which other way I can do that, which scale well between portrait and landscape and have a better performance. Even because really each textview in the next xml code will be really implemented with another linearlayout, because it have to include text and icons. Sadly I am new in stackoverflow so I can publish images

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bg1_blurred"
    android:gravity="center"
    tools:context="com.lm2a.w8opt.MainActivity" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="5" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="5" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_margin="1dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textColor="@color/txt_color_white"
                android:textSize="@dimen/text_big"
                android:background="@color/square_color_red"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:text="T" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_margin="1dp"
                android:layout_weight="4"
                android:background="#00000000"
                android:text="W" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="5" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView3"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_margin="1dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@color/square_color_yellow"
                android:text="X" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView4"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_margin="1dp"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:background="@color/square_color_blue"
                android:text="Y" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView5"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_margin="1dp"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:background="@color/square_color_green"
                android:text="Z" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: may be grid or label layout helps

Comment: Thanks for your response. But the problem is not all the rows have the same height and not all rows have the same quantity of cells

Comment: `GridLayout` allows different column/row spans; don't confuse it with `GridView`.

Comment: GridLayout is just available for API 14 and up, isn't it?

Comment: Unless this layout is going to be redrawn frequently and continuously, there's not much to gain from avoiding nested LinearLayouts, and I would think the control over the look afforded by weights and nesting outweighs that slight performance gain.

Comment: Thanks Mike, perhaps it can be giving some performance issues in low resources devices, but yes, I'm agree with you, the control using layouts and weights are wonderful. Perhaps Android guys in the future can create some optimising tool which enable to still using this way to create UI.

Comment: `GridLayout` can be imported from appCompat.7 in your SDK samples